# trying to prove equality of composition of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $S $ be the  plane  that is, $S$= {$(x,y)\mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}$} and let $f$ and $g$ be defined as $f(x,y)$= $(-x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$=$(-y,x)$ and here $f$ is the reflection about $x$ axis and $g$ is the rotation about $90$ in counterclockwise direction about the origin.
Further, defining $G$= {${f^{i}}{g^{j}} \mid i=0,1\mid j=0,1,2,3$} and * in $G$ is the composition of two functions, then we have to prove that
1. $f$ * $g^{-1}$= $g$ * $f$:       Evaluating right hand side I see that it equals to $(-y,-x)$  and for left side, $g^{-1}(x,y)$=$(x,-y)$ and so, $f$ * $g^{-1}(x,y)$=$(-x,-y)$, which clearly is not equal to RHS,and so I'm not getting what I should
I'll appreciate any reply or answer pointing out where I'm wrong, (I know,I am)maybe its the inverse of $g$ or something else, I'm ignoring here.

Thanks in advance for any replies.
P.s.: I couldn't think of anymore tags to add, so feel free to add more, if you feel there is any need.

Comment: If it interests you, there's quite a lot of literature on the subject, except with other rotations too. Just search for Dihedral Groups!

Comment: yes, actually this question is part of a problem based on dihedral groups

Comment: Ah, I see. I think there's a tag for that by the way.

Comment: yeah, there is but I didn't add it 'cause the question above doesn't involve anything related to dihedral groups, just some coordinate geometry and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(x,y)\overset{g}{\mapsto}(-y,x)$, we have $(x,y)\overset{g^{-1}}{\mapsto}\color{red}{(y,-x)}$. The claim now follows:
$$
(x,y)\overset{g^{-1}}{\mapsto}(y,-x)\overset{f}{\mapsto}(-y,-x);\quad\quad(x,y)\overset{f}{\mapsto}(-x,y)\overset{g}{\mapsto}(-y,-x).
$$

Comment: can you explian how did you get $g^{-1}$ from $g$?

Comment: Sure, start with $(x,y)\overset{g}{\mapsto}(-y,x)$. Now, relabel $-y$ as $s$ and $x$ as $t$. Then $(-y,x)=(s,t)$ and $(x,y)=(t,-s)$. Thus, $(t,-s)\overset{g}{\mapsto}(s,t)$, which implies $(s,t)\overset{g^{-1}}{\mapsto}(t,-s)$. Now, relabel $s\to x$ and $t\to y$.